# How can I format `\delta` as **Bold sloping sans serif font**

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

How can I format `\delta` as **Bold sloping sans serif font**. The journal guideline requires that **Bold sloping sans serif font**, defined by the `\mathsfbi` macro, should be used for tensors and matrices, for example `\mathsfbi{E}`. Obviously, it is suited to the normal letter. But when I use `\mathsfbi{\delta}`, it turns out that there seems no any change. My question is how can I apply it for Greek letter?

Comment: *Which* journal? I've never heard of `\mathsfbi`, myself – do you have a MWE?

Comment: No font change does often mean that the relevant font does not provide the requested shape/series.

Comment: Sloping or slanted? I'm familiar with *slanted* sans-serif fonts, but not with the sloping variety...

Comment: @Mico, it is **sloping**.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I guessed so... But I am wondering if there is any workaround for it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the font provided by `newtxsf` (or another one providing sans serif math):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,pdftexcmds,amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbi}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{bx}{sl}
\DeclareMathVersion{sfletters}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sfletters}{OML}{ntxsfmi}{b}{it}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathbfsbilow}[1]{%
  \text{\mathversion{sfletters}$\m@th#1$}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tensor}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifcat\noexpand #1\relax
    % assume Greek letter
    \edef\greek@test{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \edef\greek@test{\expandafter\@cdr\greek@test\@nil}%
    \edef\greek@test{\expandafter\@car\greek@test\@nil}%
    \edef\x{\the\lccode\expandafter`\greek@test}%
    \edef\y{\number\expandafter`\greek@test}%
    \ifnum\x=\y\relax
      % the command name starts with a lowercase letter
      \mathbfsbilow{#1}%
    \else
      \mathsfbi{#1}%
    \fi
  \else
    \mathsfbi{#1}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\tensor{T}+\tensor{\Gamma}+\tensor{\delta}$

$\tensor{\alpha}\tensor{\beta}\tensor{\gamma}$

\end{document}
```

[image]